# How to make the size of the div to the number of letters

Tags: html, css

Hi guys I am working on a chat program...

[div image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UWLh.png)

I want this div's size like :

[wanted div image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAsBM.png)

Comment: you can use 9patch image instead of full image
http://draw9patch.com/#url=http://draw9patch.com/image/btn.png&top[]=25&top[]=50&right[]=25&right[]=50&bottom[]=25&bottom[]=50&left[]=25&left[]=50

Comment: @Khunteta The question is tagged with html and css...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to their CSS:

```
  float:left; /*or right*/
  clear:both;
```

See this fiddle for an example with alternating positions: https://jsfiddle.net/ujpyxm22/1/